# Не проходит валидация, в чем может быть причина

Tags: php, yii2

Форма:

```
     class BuildForm extends Model
    {
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $build;

    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $manifest;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    public $is_pinned;

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['build', 'manifest'], 'required'],
            [['build'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'ipa'],
            [['manifest'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'plist'],
            ['is_pinned', 'boolean', 'trueValue' => true, 'falseValue' => false],
            ['is_pinned', 'default', 'value' => false],
        ];
    }
}
```

Вью:

```
<p>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($buildForm, 'build')->fileInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($buildForm, 'manifest')->fileInput() ?>

    <button>Submit</button>

    <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
</p>
```

Контроллер:

```
public function actionView($name)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($name);
        $buildForm = new BuildForm();

        $buildsDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $model->getBuilds()->orderBy(['uploaded_at' => SORT_DESC]),
        ]);

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost){
            $buildForm->build = UploadedFile::getInstance($buildForm, 'build' );
            $buildForm->manifest = UploadedFile::getInstance($buildForm, 'manifest');

            if ($buildForm->validate()) {
                $model->getAppContainer()->addBuild(
                    $buildForm->build,
                    $buildForm->manifest
                );

                $model->cleanupBuildsCollection();

                return $this->refresh();
            }
        }
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $model,
            'buildForm' => $buildForm,
            'buildsDataProvider' => $buildsDataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отключите проверку файла по mime type

```
[['build'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'ipa', 'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false],
```

Comment: спасибо, да, так и есть

Answer (score 0):

Перед рендером страницы (или после безуспешной валидации) в контроллере напишите

```
var_dump($buildForm->getErrors()); die();
```

и узнаете в чём именно у Вас возникла ошибка

Comment: array(2) { ["build"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(50) "Only files with these extensions are allowed: ipa." } ["manifest"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(52) "Only files with these extensions are allowed: plist." } } –

Comment: Написано что разрешены только файлы с расширениями ipa и plist. Собственно как у Вас в модели и написано в rules: `[['build'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'ipa'],
            [['manifest'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'plist'],` возможно загружаете файлы не с этими расширениями?

Comment: дело в том, что такие файлы я и пытаюсь загрузить

Comment: Уберите тогда вообще из rules эти ограничения `'extensions' => 'ipa'` и `'extensions' => 'plist'` и посмотрите будет ли работать. Уверен что будет. И скорее всего сейчас Вы где то ошибаетесь, а не yii. )

Comment: Возникает ошибка дальше ) `public function checkFile()
    {
        if (!preg_match($this->filenamePattern, $this->file->name)) {
            throw new Exception("File name doesn't match pattern", 10);
        }
    }`

Comment: типа не соответствует этой маске `protected $filenamePattern = '/\.ipa$/';`

Comment: Ну теперь уж разбирайтесь с классом, который загружает файлы и с этой ошибкой. Почему не проходит валидация - разобрались.